# how to update the Text widget value if user enter the value in Textfield

Tags: flutter, text, controller, textfield

i want to update the Text widget value when user enter the text in textfield, here is what i am doing.

```
String getemail="";
 _userDetails() async{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
     
      getemail=myPrefs.getString('email'); 
 }); 
   }

 TextEditingController email=new TextEditingController();
Column(children: <Widget>[
             TextField(
             
             onChanged: (value) {
               setState(() {
                 valueText = value;
               });
             },
             controller: email,
             decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: getemail,icon: Icon(Icons.email)),
           ),
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 260, 0, 0),
      child: Row(children: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.email,color: Colors.blue,size: 27,),
        
        Text(email.text==""?getemail:email.text,style:TextStyle(fontSize: profileFontsize))
      ],),
    ),
```

It is not printing anything on text widget, please help how to do this.

**Update:**

Strange! this `email.text==""?getemail:email.text` condition was not working before, but now it is working!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Text(email.text == " " ? getemail : valueText, 
     style:TextStyle(fontSize: profileFontsize),
    )
```

Comment: it is sending this error ```A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'
```

Comment: get email is returning a null value.

Comment: but i print it in initState() function it has a value!